# MobX State Tree - exporting the model validation?

Tags: mobx

Is there a recommended way to export the model and use it as validation in a server side request?

i.e If I have a user

```
User = types.model("User", {
    id: types.identifier(),
    firstName: types.string,
    lastName: types.string,
    leftHanded: types.optional(types.boolean, false),
  })
```

And then an express endpoint

```
app.put('/user', function(req, res) {
  const user = User.create(req.body);
  const record = db.push(getSnapshot(user)).write();
  res.send(record);
});
```

If the server is bundled with the app then everything is fine but what if I want to decouple them and make a standalone API server ?

Does it make sense to have the domain models as a separate package?

(would love to add `mobx-state-tree` tag but I don't have rep)

Answer (score 0):

Yes it make sense to have separate module for domain. You even can move all domain logic there. And if domain is large and app is complex this module can be even developed separately by somebody else.
For complex systems separate package is good choose. Disadvantage of this  you will have models inside `node_modules` directory. This is not very convenient. I prefer to have it inside `src/` to simplify modification.
Another way to use same part of code in several projects is *git submodules* and *git subtree* (better).